# OAuth 2.0 in enterprise applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0

We are using ASP.NET for development and by default it uses OAuth with third-party services disabled. I have a few questions on this subject:

1. In enterprise software can we use OAuth even though we would not be using any social site logins?
2. What are other options besides OAuth for enterprise authentication and authorization?
3. By default it uses ASP.NET Identity, since it just requires a token, can I totally bypass the ASP.NET Identity and issue token myself?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth was possibly made so popular due to its adoption by major social players like Google, Facebook and Twitter.

<sup>**(1)**</sup> Having said that you can and it's indeed already being used across a wide range of applications that have nothing to do with social logins.

<sup>**(2)**</sup> Before OAuth2, enterprises were mostly using SAML or WS-Federation to solve authentication and authorization related issues. The most common scenario for these protocols was to implement a SSO (Single Sign On) solution. Although they are still being actively used today, the tendency would be for you to adopt OAuth2 and/or [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) as alternatives.

<sup>**(3)**</sup> Like you said, if you have a system that consumes tokens it will probably will not care which technology is used to generate the tokens and instead is only concerned in ensuring the token is valid. This would mean that yes, you can generate the tokens yourself as long as they meet the consumer criteria (or you adapt the consumer to meet the producer criteria). You should, however, consider a few things...

**It's really easy to make authentication work** in the sense - **yay, my user can authenticate**.

**It's significantly complex to do it in a secure way** so that you don't end up with - **damn, my application just got owned**.

Having the possibility to do so you should delegate everything you can to a trusted third-party library or service that is focused on authentication and that will keep up the pace in the always changing security landscape. <sub>If you're looking for options I would recommend checking [Auth0](https://auth0.com/); of course you should know that I'm biased because I ended up working there.</sub>